# Flatten nested JSON to dataframe in R

Tags: r, json

I am trying to flatten a nested JSON file from within R,

Here is my current code

```
library(jsonlite)
json_file <- "json file"
json_data = fromJSON(json_file, flatten = FALSE)
flat_data = as.data.frame(json_data)
```

However i am getting the below error

> flat_data = as.data.frame(json_data)
>   Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 13, 3201

Here is a sample of my JSON structure

```
{
    "RIDE":{
        "STARTTIME":"2020\/01\/05 22:27:49 UTC ",
        "RECINTSECS":1,
        "DEVICETYPE":"Garmin FR735XT ",
        "IDENTIFIER":" ",
        "TAGS":{
            "Aerobic Training Effect":"3.8 ",
            "Athlete":"Chuck Finley",
            "Data":" ",
            "Device":"Garmin",
            "Device Info":"HR Garmin 2327",
            "File Format":" ",
            "Filename":"2020_01_06_06_27_49.json ",
            "Month":"January ",
            "Performance Condition":"-5 ",
            "Recovery Time":"  ",
            "Source Filename":"A1662750_2020_01_06_06_27_49.gz ",
            "Sport":"Run ",
            "SubSport":" ",
            "VO2max detected":"61.7 ",
            "Weekday":"Mon ",
            "Workout Code":" ",
            "Year":"2020 "
        },
        "INTERVALS":[
            { "NAME":"Lap 1 ", "START": 0, "STOP": 249, "COLOR":"#000000", "PTEST":"false" },
            { "NAME":"Lap 2 ", "START": 250, "STOP": 504, "COLOR":"#000000", "PTEST":"false" }
        ],
        "SAMPLES":[
            { "SECS":0, "KM":0, "KPH":0, "HR":104, "ALT":14, "LAT":-40.402758436, "LON":175.0371112, "SLOPE":0, "LRBALANCE":0, "RCAD":109.5, "RVERT":0.47, "RCON":273 },
            { "SECS":1, "KM":0.00056, "KPH":0, "HR":104, "ALT":14, "LAT":-40.402758436, "LON":175.0371112, "SLOPE":0, "LRBALANCE":24.87, "RCAD":109.5, "RVERT":0.47, "RCON":273 }
        ],
        "XDATA":[
        {
            "NAME" : "EXTRA",
            "VALUES" : [ "STANCETIMEPERCENT", "VERTICALRATIO", "STEPLENGTH", "FIELD_88", "ACTIVITYTYPE", "PERFORMANCECONDITION" ],
            "UNITS" : [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ],
            "SAMPLES" : [
                { "SECS":1, "KM":0, "VALUES":[ 48.5, 0, 0, 300, 1, 0 ] },
                { "SECS":2, "KM":0, "VALUES":[ 48.5, 4.96, 891, 300, 1, 0 ] }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am quite new to R, so any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get any error when I use your example. I do use "test_file.json", i.e. the name of the file containing JSON, instead of "json file", a string which `fromJSON` will try to interpret as JSON. `as.data.frame` works as expected and produces a data frame of the JSON data.

Comment: Hi @gersht, Thanks - I have tested using the data i provided and it worked, however that is only test data. Which has allowed me to narrow down the problem, In the real data set there is 13 records for "INTERVALS" and 3201 records for "Sample". Thanks!

Comment: I assume your question is solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the file name. Json file should be **.json**

```
json_file <- "json file.json"
```