# How to flatten a dataframe in this way in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have this data frame `df`:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))
> df$b <- list(list(),list(id=c('d', 'e')))
> df
  a    b
1 1 NULL
2 2 d, e
> df$b
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] "d" "e"
```

How do I get the following data frame:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,2),b=c(NA,'d','e'))
> df2
  a    b
1 1 <NA>
2 2    d
3 2    e
```

In other words, there should be a new row for every list item in column `b`.

I looked at these three things:

```
jsonlite::flatten(df)
rlang::flatten(df)
purrr::flatten(df)
```

and also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315308/how-to-flatten-json-object-into-a-dataframe-in-r) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853523/flatten-nested-json-to-dataframe-in-r) questions, and nothing seemed quite right.

Yes, I'm getting this data from an API that returns json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unnest` with the `keep_empty` as `TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    unnest(c(b), keep_empty = TRUE) %>% 
    unnest(c(b), keep_empty = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a b    
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 <NA> 
#2     2 d    
#3     2 e
```

Comment: Great! Why do you need two `unnest` calls? I ran just the one, and it looked like it did nothing.

Comment: @dfrankow because you have nested `list()` inside and it won't recursively flatten

Comment: I see, each `unnest` removes a `list`. You're my hero.